# Maven exec safe in production

Tags: maven, apache-kafka

Is it unsafe in any way to use `maven exec` to run Java code in a production environment? Currently, I am running Kafka, Schema Registry and Zookeeper in production using the shell wrappers script that ship with each distribution. I was wondering if it would be safe (assuming I apply all of the proper flags passed to Java by the wrapper script) to instead to run something like `maven exec {schema-registry,kafka,zookeeper}-conf.xml`?

This question isn't meant to be specific to Kafka, Schema Registry and Zookeeper. I am more wondering if there are any qualities of Maven that make it inappropriate for use in production in this way.

Comment: This sounds a bit like you're adding some unneeded complexity. Nevertheless you could do that. Could be a bastard to maintain though

Answer (score 0):

If you like to execute something in production I would recommend to create a script which calls you java application (creating classpath etc). This can be done manually or you let generate such scripts via [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) during the build and only deliver the script including your app to your production environment or better in the end only a single zip file which contains everything you need.

Otherwise you have all the build needed stuff like local cache `$HOME/.m2/repository` etc. configuration which is needed for Maven and of course the Maven installation in your production environment which does not really make sense.